# Power Series Problem.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\sum a_nx^n$ has a finite radius of convergence, say $R$, and $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n$, show that if the series converges at $R$ then it also converges at $-R$ .

What I did: Applying the root test to the series:  $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_nx^n|^{1/n}$, 
Now the series converges at $x = R$, thus we can conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}|(an)|^{1/n}|R| < 1$.
Now for $x = -R$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n(-R)^n|^{1/n}$, which equals $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}|R|$ which is already less than $1$, so it converges for $x = -R$. Is this correct ??

Comment: No, you can't conclude that limit is $<1.$ An example that shows this is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n^2.$

Comment: @zhw. so how to show that it converges for x = -R ?

Comment: Does Lt mean $\limsup$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen no, Limit as n approaches to infinity , here i didn't use the limitSup definition , just tried the root test directly .

Comment: @RohitDuggal There's no reason to believe that the limit exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Root Test is not an if and only if statement.  Convergence of the series does not imply that the limit is less than 1, in fact there are convergent series such that the limit does not exist at all.  (You can replace the limit with a lim sup, but the test might still be inconclusive.)

Your argument doesn't use the fact that the $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n$.  In general, without a constraint like this the result is false.  If you set $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, for instance, then the series converges at $R = 1$ but not at $-R = -1$.  My hint on how to use this condition is to write out the series for $x = -R$, and try to check that it converges absolutely.

Comment: Here's what i tried :
(-R)^n <= (R)^n , 

a(n)(-R)^n <= a(n)(R)^n { a(n) >= 0} , 

|a(n)(-R)^n| <= |a(n)(R)^n| , 

Sigma|a(n)(-R)^n| <= Sigma[a(n)(R)^n] ,

Now Sigma[a(n)(R)^n] converges as its given so by Weierstrass M test the series converges at x = -R. is it ok ?

Comment: @Rohit Duggal that does suffice to show absolute convergence, but note that once you start introducing absolute values your $\le$ inequalities can be replaced by equalities.